# MongoDB projection not excluding fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Tech Stack: React, Node and MongoDB (Native Driver).

I am using a simple MongoDB findOne method to find a user by email. In this findOne method, I have included projection field, that should exclude or include certain fields from the MongoDB document in the database.

The response is sent to a callback function that logs the user out (I will demonstrate).

My question: When i use this projection extra paramater, nothing I do affects the result i get back from the request. Am I missing something or doing it incorrectly?

Code:

MongoDB method:

```
static findUserInDatabase = ( method, searchParam, callback ) => {
        const db = getDb();
        if ( method === "email" ) {

            //This is where I have the issue
            db.collection( process.env.USERSCOLLECTION ).findOne( { email: searchParam.trim() }, { password: 0 } ).then( r => callback( r) ).catch( e => callback( e ) );
        } else {
            db.collection( process.env.USERSCOLLECTION ).findOne( { tokens: searchParam.trim() } ).then( r => callback( r ) ).catch( e => callback( e ) );
        }
    };
```

Node code that logs the user:

```
User.findUserInDatabase( "email", friendEmail.email, ( friend ) => {
        console.log( friend );
        //Inside of this console.log I get all of the fields of the user, such as password field. 
    } );
```

Here is the MongoDB documentation:

"The following operation finds a document in the bios collection and returns only the name, contribs and _id fields:"

```
db.bios.findOne(
    { //Query },
    { name: 1, contribs: 1 }
)
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the query. Once try to check that it is not going in else part!

Comment: It is going correctly into the first part, But I am still getting all of the fields from the document :(

Comment: Try getting only those fields which are required like { firstname: 1, lastname: 1 } so that It be more clear that only deselection of fields {password: 0} is not working.

Comment: I've tried that too, with getting only email: 1 for example, still everything is returned, very weird

Comment: That's weird! the query is exactly the same. My suggestion is to check that is there any middleware that is preventing the selection query or something else?